# How to initialize empty pandas Panel

Tags: python, pandas

I'm trying to fill pandas Panel in a `for` loop:

```
dp = pd.Panel()
for i in range(x):
    # read data in 2D numpy array as 'arr'
    dp[i] = arr
```

which raises:

```
ValueError: shape of value must be (0, 0), shape of given object was (309, 495)
```

Trying:

```
dp = pd.Panel()
for i in range(x):
    ...
    dp.update({i: arr})
```

does not raise error, but after completion I get empty pane.

If I initialize Panel with single item, I can use the first method to update the panel, but I want to initialize empty Panel.

So how to initialize empty pandas Panel, to be able to add data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems it is necessary to initialize Panel with the shape of expected data, so in my case this worked fine:

```
dp = pd.Panel(major_axis=range(309), minor_axis=range(495))
for i in range(x):
    # read data in 2D numpy array as 'arr'
    dp[i] = arr
```

Same applies to DataFrame - if user wants to add a column to empty DataFrame it will fail if DataFrame index is not defined, so:

```
df = DataFrame(index=range(5))
```

is the right way to initialize empty DataFrame with 5 rows.